# Converting EDI 837I to XML using BizTalk server

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I tried with another file,While converting to EDI 837 I to  XML the below errors arraised. Are these fields are mandatory fields?

I manually passed values to ISA09, ISA10 and ISA13 then I am receiving

> Error encountered during parsing. The X12 interchange with id '         ', with sender id '  ', receiver id '   ' had the following errors:
>
> Error: 4 (Field level error)  SegmentID: ISA  Position in TS: 1   Data
>   Element ID: ISA09     Position in Segment: 9  Data Value:         8:
>   Invalid Date
>
> Error: 5 (Field level error)  SegmentID: ISA  Position in TS: 1   Data
>   Element ID: ISA10     Position in Segment: 10     Data Value:         9:
>   Invalid Time
>
> Error: 6 (Field level error)  SegmentID: ISA  Position in TS: 1   Data
>   Element ID: ISA13     Position in Segment: 13     Data Value:             6:
>   Invalid character in data element

Comment: Without more information, I'd say the error message is the answer, an invalid date, invalid time and an invalid character.

Answer (score 0):

ISA09 is YYMMDD formatted.

ISA10 is HHMM formatted.

ISA13 is n8, meaning 8 digits.

**ISA is fixed length** so numbers must be **0 padded** and text space padded.

Have you done the [EDI Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/tutorial-2-edi-interface-developer-tutorial) for BizTalk?